# Convert nested list of multi-labels to one-hot representation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new to data science and sklearn.

I've got a list of strings as follow:

```
[
 ['JAVA', 'JAVASCRIPT', 'PYTHON'],
 ['JAVASCRIPT', 'PYTHON', 'NODEJS'], 
 ['JAVASCRIPT', 'JAVA'], 
 ['JAVASCRIPT', 'PYTHON'],  
 ['JAVA']
]
```

How am I supposed to convert the above string labels into numerical labels?

I'm trying to obtain the numerical labels,

where each one of them represents a vector in a particular dimension as below:

```
    JAVA PYTHON JAVASCRIPT NODEJS 
1st    1      1          1      0
2nd    0      1          1      1
3rd    1      0          1      0
4th    0      1          1      0
5th    1      0          0      0
```

and then use them in a cosine similarity formula.

I was told that sklearn labelEncoder can be used for the conversion to numerical labels, but I'm not sure how? Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sklearn's [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html), which precisely aims at transforming between iterable of iterables and a multilabel format:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

l = [
 ['JAVA', 'JAVASCRIPT', 'PYTHON'],
 ['JAVASCRIPT', 'PYTHON', 'NODEJS'], 
 ['JAVASCRIPT', 'JAVA'], 
 ['JAVASCRIPT', 'PYTHON'],  
 ['JAVA']
]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
a = mlb.fit_transform(l)
pd.DataFrame(a, columns=mlb.classes_)

   JAVA  JAVASCRIPT  NODEJS  PYTHON
0     1           1       0       1
1     0           1       1       1
2     1           1       0       0
3     0           1       0       1
4     1           0       0       0
```